# MySQL query syntax and trim

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get an error on the MYSQLI query, saying that there's an error with the syntax on line 2. I've addslashed/trimmed all my variables and so commas/dots shouldn't be breaking the command. However, one issue is my file name does contain spaces, so I'm not sure if `Trim` is a good option since it removes the spaces, that is the second issue.

I have the following php/mysql code:

Its giving me the error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO files (f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES ('ISYF.doc', 'application/mswo' at line 2

the names you see on top are file names/file types

I have tried inputting the mysql command directly into the database, and it works, even when the filename contains spaces.. but on browser, it tells me i have a syntax error...

***OK i did more tests, it appears to me the START TRANSACTION;/COMMIT; are the ones causing the issue, i highly suspect the semi-colons which they come with, anyone thinks the same way?***

```
<?php  
session_start();
 require 'config.php';
 //I'm using mysqli_ as an example, it should be PDO

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$foldername = "updatefiles/";
if (isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['expire']) && isset($_POST['groupid'])){
    $title=addslashes(trim($_POST['update']));
    $description=addslashes(trim($_POST['description']));
    $expire=addslashes(trim($_POST['expire']));
    $groupid=addslashes(trim($_POST['groupid']));

    $fileupload = addslashes(trim(basename( $_FILES['file']['name'])));
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $foldername . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);


     $uploadsql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO files (f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES ('$fileupload', '$fileType', '$fileSize');
INSERT INTO posts (category, description, posttitle, userid, expire, group_id) VALUES ('updates','$description', '$title','{$_SESSION['userid']}', '$expire','$groupid' );
COMMIT;");

if (!$uploadsql) {
echo mysqli_error($mysqli); 

} else {
echo"successandfile";   

} 

}else {
echo"formnotsubmitted"; 


}

?>
```

Comment: does it contain spaces or linebreaks ? sometimes it looks like space but its a linebreake. Is it possible that a linebreake is in there ?

Comment: yeah the filename contains spaces, am not sure how to keep the spaces without affecting the query

Comment: could you post the echo of filename ?

Comment: Why do you have multiple queries in your `mysqli_query(..)`-statement? Why are you messing with `addslashes(..)` instead of using prepared queries?

Comment: use {$_SESSION["userid"]} instead of {$_SESSION['userid']}

Comment: @ShehrozAsmat this has non to do with that. Since he uses {} brakets it doesnt matters

Comment: i have spaces and dots, the error is mostly related to the filename, which in my opinion shouldn't be wrong, i tried inputing the query directly into the database, and it works, so I'm thinking something with the variables

Comment: @dwza i have appended the complete error as above.

Comment: By the way what is the use of Transaction here, there is no way to rollback in case of error.

Comment: transaction is because i need to combine the two queries to get them to execute together, if not separate queries in terms of error handling would be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) can only execute one SQL statement.  Use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead.

In your case here:

```
$uploadsql = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,"START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO files (f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES ('$fileupload', '$fileType', '$fileSize');
INSERT INTO posts (category, description, posttitle, userid, expire, group_id) VALUES ('updates','$description', '$title','{$_SESSION['userid']}', '$expire','$groupid' );
COMMIT;");
```

Although, I would tend to split this up to catch errors and roll the transaction back.  That is the whole point of transactions.

Comment: Hi, i actually just realised this was the issue,i used thismysqli_query($mysqli, "START TRANSACTION");

$a1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO files (f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES ('".$fileupload."', '".$fileType."', '".$fileSize."')");
$a2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO posts (category, description, posttitle, userid, expire, group_id) VALUES ('updates','".$description."', '".$title."','{$_SESSION['userid']}', '".$expire."','".$groupid."' )");

if ($a1 and $a2) {
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"COMMIT");
 echo"success";
} else {        
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"ROLLBACK");
 echo"error";
}

Answer (score 0):

use {$_SESSION["userid"]} instead of {$_SESSION['userid']}

Comment: in any case, as explained, it does not matter as I'm using {}, so it does not change anything. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

var_dump, $fileType and fileSize variable before using it in INSERT query, here may be the problem with single and double quotes...

```
   var_dump($fileType);
   var_dump($fileSize);

   INSERT INTO files (f_name, f_type, f_size) VALUES ('$fileupload', '$fileType',   
   '$fileSize');
```

Comment: that returns me string(9) "image/png"
int(701722), and the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving multiple queries to `mysqli_query()`.  You Can't Do That.™

Call it four times, once for `START TRANSACTION`, once for your each of your `INSERT` operations, and once for `COMMIT`.